# Cocos2d JS Data Storage

Tags: javascript, database, local-storage, storage, cocos2d-js

What is the best way to store data that aren't just high score type data?

For instance if I have several different types of units, I want to the store information of these units (E.g. Damage, health, texture, etc.). In a relational database I would have a table 'Units'.

So what is the best database equivalent for cocos2d js? Is it fine to use cc.sys.localstorage for this amount of data? I read that cc.sys.localstorage uses SQLLite, is this true?

If localstorage is a valid option, I was thinking of using JSON as the value of the key/value pair?

Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of alternatives, but: is that data going to change often based on your player's actions? (meaning, is it "save data"?) or is it just data your game uses for types of units and the such, and it shouldn't change except for an update on your part? LocalStorage is good for the first, but not the second, I'd just use a flat JSON file for that.

Comment: Thanks man. I was referring to your second option. And yes I also decided to just use json files :). At least now I feel comfortable with my decision. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No prob. Just remember that's really easy to over-complicate this things, so try and always go for the simplest route.